# Why is col-sm-push-6 also executed in LG mode?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a footer on my website with six content blocks.
Depending on the breakpoints, I want to have them in 1x6, 2x3 or 3x2 format.

Without the push and pull classes, the blocks raster is working well on all breakpoints.
But you can imaging that I want to reorder some blocks if it flips from 3x2 to 2x3 format.

```
<!-- footer -->
<div class="footer">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">                
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-4">
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix hidden-sm"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

In SM mode the reordering works fine.
But in LG mode it is still executing the col-sm-push-6 command because it push the 3th div out of the screen.

Is col-sm-push-6 not SM only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `col-md-push-0` / `col-md-pull-0` to "reset" the push/pull for the other grid sizes..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  
            <div class="well"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="well"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-4 col-md-push-0">
            <div class="well"> </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix hidden-sm"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-md-4  col-md-pull-0">
            <div class="well"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="well"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="well"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/126837

Comment: So col-sm-pull-* classes are seen as "from" breakpoints? Always executed for SM breakpoint and larger?